# Laravel - delete all properties from record except name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6, soft-delete

I have a user table and user can delete their account and there data deletes. It's a soft delete. What I want is to delete all attributes except the name.

Can I do something like

```
$user->delete()->except(['name'']) ?
```

The record must be soft deleted just with the data removed.

Comment: what are you trying to do? If you delete a record, the whole row will be deleted. You can not only safe an attribute and delete others

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `SoftDeletes` trait.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User  extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;

}
```

But make sure you have a `deleted_at` column in your table.